# How to set the Object3D position and rotation same as the added mesh ? [three.js]

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

When I create an Object3D model and add the meshes to it, how do I set the position and rotation of the added mesh to same as the Object3D model, like when I rotate and position the Object3D there should be no difference in angle of rotation between the Object3D and the added mesh. How do I achieve such result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Object3D model is called `obj`, then after `obj.add(mesh)` any changes to `obj` (position/rotation/scale) will change `mesh` in the same way.

If instead you don't want `mesh` to be attached to `obj`, but you still want them to have the same position and rotation, you could try

```
mesh.position = obj.position;
mesh.rotation = obj.rotation;
```

Hope this helps!