# three js same position (reference) for 2 Object3D()

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

I am trying to add 2 (or more) Meshes to the same scene, but i want all the Object3D to share the same position (but with a different rotation for each object).

I know the ".copy()" method, but in my case, there are so many objects and using a loop to change the position of all the objects (60 times per seconds) is resulting a poor performance.

So, I tried to use the same position reference for the objects:

```
var o=new THREE.Object3D(); // the first object
var p=new THREE.Object3D(); // the second object

o.position=p.position; // the position of the first object becomes the reference to the position of the second object

o.position==p.position; // false, but why?
```

But it isn't working and I don't get why!

My question is:

- Is it possible to change the position reference of a THREE.Object3D()?
- And if it isn't, how can I improve the performance of my scene?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: seems to works for someone (this answer is exactly what i can't do): [How to set the Object3D position and rotation same as the added mesh ? [three.js]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147385/how-to-set-the-object3d-position-and-rotation-same-as-the-added-mesh-three-js?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905929/three-js-2xmeshes-using-same-vector-as-position/.

Comment: Add your meshes as children of a parent `Object3D` and then set the parent's position in the render loop.